# Designing a Process Monitor Windows Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, process, windows-services

I'm designing a Windows Service that maintains a list of processes. It can run tasks on them. For example - stop a specific process (within its list), restart a specific process, run a new process and add it to the list, etc.

This Windows Service is controlled by a web app, through a WCF service - the Windows Service runs a WCF service, and the web app connects to that WCF service. The WCF service exports methods such as `Restart(int id)` and `Stop(int id)`.

I have several questions:

- When a process unexpectedly closes (for example, because of an internal error), the service should update a value in some database. Right now, to do this, I'm just having a thread that every 30 seconds it checks if the process is running or not.

  Is this the right to do this? Should I use the `Exit` event?
- When the service closes, for *any* reason, **all** of the processes that it maintains shall close too. What is the right way to do this?

  I was thinking about just loop through the list and kill all processes when the service's `OnClose()` is called. The problem with this is that the `OnClose()` event is not always being called. For example, what if the service unexpectedly closes? It won't call `OnClose()`.
- How should I represent each task (for example - restart a process or stop a process)?

  Right now I'm using `System.Threading.Tasks`. Is it the right way?

This service should be highly scalable, with minimum mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: it sounds as if you are reinventing the Windows Service Control Manager?

Comment: the problem with SCM is that it is not extendable. In my service, I also have custom methods, not only 'restart' and 'stop'.

Comment: Then simply write a custom app. to send those messages to the SCM hosted process. Windows services support this model.

Answer (score 0):

For closing the processes when the service closes, i think following steps can do the job for you.

1. Write a small program which can close the processes you want to close.
2. Go to Service Control Manager and right click on your service.
3. Go to Recovery tab and specify your program for execution under First Failure, Second Failure and Subsequest Failure listboxs.

Hope this would help.